# Which tool to use to design and export a website

Tags: web-development, web-server

I want to design a website for an educational institution. In the past I have done so using [Artisteer](http://www.artisteer.com/). In Artisteer I exported the project and they uploaded it to their server and that was that.

I don't have access to Artisteer anymore and I would like to find another tool to use to do the same, meaning I don't want hosting but to be able to export my project after I am done designing it and drop it on their server. I still want to be able to change things or make updates if need be.

A few additional information:

I run Windows 10 and I'd prefer something that was free of charge or not too expensive. Also it doesn't necessarily have to be for commercial use.
The website is not going to be very large, 5 main pages at the most along with some subpages. It will have text and pictures and maybe a slideshow. Polls and tests are not needed. A database backend or Youtube videos are also not needed. 
The server is at the institution and it can handle HTML but I am not sure about PHP.

I have looked at Wordpress but it's not very straightforward, at least compared to artisteer and I haven't seen the option to export the project.

Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What OS must it run on? What features (apart from the export) do you need? How much are you willing to pay – or must the software come free of charge? Must it allow for commercial use as well?

Comment: How large is the website going to be (# pages)? What features is that website going to need? Just a simple presentation of texts and images? Do need a way to manage your images or is just dumping them into a page good enough? Input forms or any kind of other feedback (polls, tests)? A database backend? Youtube videos? Please [edit] your question and say yes or no for all.

Comment: *drop it on their server* I assume that is the server of the institution? What can it handle - just HTML, or PHP as well?

Comment: Have you looked at using Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal? If so, why don't these meet the requirements?

Comment: I answered the questions, if there's anything else let me know! Thank you!

Comment: I've never used it, but Grav might be a good option: https://getgrav.org. Its a flat file CMS which doesn't need a database.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Macaw](http://macaw.co/). It used to be a paid (and expensive!) software but it is now free since they were bought by InVision.

Maybe it is a little complex to use at first (help section [here](https://help.macaw.co/hc/en-us)) but it really is a professionnal software with loads of functionalities such as making your website adaptable for mobile devices. If you have an understanding of HTML you should have no problem making a simple site with it.

Comment: This looks pretty cool, but it also looks like it is end of life and will never be updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just building a static HTML site, you don't need anything more than a text editor and a browser.

### Text Editor

For your text editor, I would recommend something that supports basic syntax highlighting for HTML, CSS, and Javascript.  Suggestions:

- [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)
- [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit)
- [Brackets](http://brackets.io/)

### Templates

I would also recommend that you start with some sort of pre-designed template, rather than trying to create everything from scratch (unless you are a professional graphic designer AND have a lot of experience with CSS).  Suggestions:

- [Azmind](http://azmind.com/)
- [Start Bootstrap](https://startbootstrap.com/)

Stay away from Wordpress if you don't want your site to be a massive target for hackers.

Comment: Unless you really like coding by hand, I'd suggest a good WYSIWYG editor that supports templating, etc.  Dreamweaver, you may be able to find a "used copy" of a pre-subscription model release...

Answer (score 0):

I've used [BlueGriffon](http://www.bluegriffon.org/) which is a free WYSIWYG web page builder. There is also a very good tutorial to work you thru building web pages. It has a nice interface and is very capable.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has many frameworks you can use.

https://laravel.com/

There will be some coding involved, and it does have a learning curve.  However, when its done you should be able to upload the whole folder.  When you get more advanced project some dependencies may have to be installed.